# Wordpress form conditional repeating

Tags: jquery, forms, web, wordpress

I have a form that asks via drop-down how many locations you want to use, and the options are numbered 1-5.

I have conditional formatting for several paragraph text boxes that will show one for each location depending on what is selected (if 2 locations are selected, then paragraph boxes for "location 1" and "location 2" will show, etc).

These conditional displaying boxes are the same across all the locations. Is it possible to model one of the boxes and have the same structure of boxes repeat multiple times based on how many locations were selected?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use a function with a loop. The loop would contain the model box, and the loop would be governed by a counter variable assigned by the number of locations selected.

This could be called by your form either through pure Javascript (ie a JS function), or could use a PHP function called by a PHP post/get or by AJAX.

Comment: can I add this directly though the CMS of wordpress or do I need to edit the actual server files?

Comment: That depends ... I can't think off-hand how you would easily do that with a standard WP install. I figure there is SOME plugin that would do it...but I'm not sure of your setup. If your plugin doesn't cover this functionality, you're probably going to have to edit the files. The BEST way would be to add a 'custom' plugin ... you can also use a plugin like Code Snippets to just drop in your custom PHP code without writing your own plugin.